# Issue with HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync Not Working from ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await

I have created an ASP.NET Core 2.1 service and I can call it just fine from a console application. However, when I use the very same code to call it from an ASPX page, it does not return an answer. It just never goes past _client.PostAsJsonAsync and seems to run forever. It should only take a handful of seconds to go through that line. Any idea on what I am missing?

```
List<OutputAddress> outputAddresses = RunAsync(inputAddresses).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

static async Task<List<OutputAddress>> RunAsync(List<InputAddress> addresses)
{
    // Update port # in the following line.
    _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<servername>/GeocodeAPI/");
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Geocode/Addresses", addresses);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OutputAddress>>(result);
        }
        else
            return null;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

=======================

Huge thank you to Nkosi for their response. Here's what I had to change:

Function calling ASP.NET Core service

```
        static async Task<List<OutputAddress>> RunAsync(List<InputAddress> addresses)
        {
            _client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://<servername>/GeocodeAPI/");
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            _client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Geocode/Addresses", addresses);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OutputAddress>>(result);
                }
                else
                    return null;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Function calling the above function (RunAsync): added async keyword

```
private async void ReadCsvFile(string filepath)
{
    ...
    List<OutputAddress> outputAddresses = await RunAsync(inputAddresses);
    ...
}
```

Added Async="true" to aspx code:

```
<%@ Page ... Async="true" %>
```

Comment: Mixing async-await and blocking calls like `.Result;` can cause deadlocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing async-await and blocking calls like `.Result;` can cause deadlocks

await the calls to getting the content

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Also, if using async-await, go async all the way.

```
List<OutputAddress> outputAddresses = await RunAsync(inputAddresses);
```

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Thanks so much Nkosi!

Answer (score 0):

Beware of how you're using asynchronous code in ASP.NET Web Forms.

You need to use [page async tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask).

That being said, nothing in async changes the HTTP protocol and, if you want some behavior on the client side, you need to implement it on the client, as [Anu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7633386/anu) [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207896/402366).